# Sending large number of SMS via AWS SNS in a few seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a requirement to send a large number of SMS (potentially thousands) in a few seconds directly to phone numbers via the AWS SNS service.

We are getting an error message as follows due to the limitation of 20 messages per second from the downstream providers.

```
"message":"Rate exceeded","code":"Throttling"
```

My question is what is the proper way to implement such a requirement? Currently, we have implemented a cronjob that checks for failed SMS deliveries and attempt to resend them again as a quick solution to the errors.

Should i use a queuing system like AWS SQS to reduce the frequency of the sending to avoid hitting the message per second limit?

Or should i just implement a delay mechanism in our application to reduce the frequency?

Or is having a cronjob to resend failed SMS good enough already?

Appreciate if anyone can share some experience and advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your account does not have enough delivery capacity (phone numbers to send SMS *from*) to be able to handle more than 20 TPS. SNS has some shared phone numbers that customers can use for certain countries but if you want to deliver thousands of SMS in a few seconds, you will need dedicated origination identities.

You can read more about the different types of origination identities available and how to purchase them here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities.html.

Once that is done, your account will be able to publish more than 20 TPS, and you will not need to queue or retry messages on your own.

Comment: Hi @bjrnt, thanks for your response.

I have kinda of resolve it by raising a ticket to AWS Support to increase the TPS for their downstream providers in the region that i am sending SMS to.

Cheers!